# How to make a hash call in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
 n <- c("foo","bar","qux","qux","bar")
 k <- c(100,200,300,400,500)
 z <- c("z","w","x","y","v")
 df1 <- data.frame(n,k,z)
 df1 
   n   k z
1 foo 100 z
2 bar 200 w
3 qux 300 x
4 qux 400 y
5 bar 500 v
```

Given a second data frame

```
l <- c("k1","k2","k3","k4","k5")
n2 <- c("foo","bar","qux","qux","bar")  # name difference of (n2) is intentional
df2 <- data.frame(n2,l)
   n2 l
1 foo k1
2 bar k2
3 qux k3
4 qux k4
5 bar k5
```

I want to create the third data frame with the following condition:

> Use `df1` as a source to create *third dataframe* and the
>   checking     reference is **n** for every row in `df1` with respect to **n2** of `df2`.

So in the end I'd like to have this:

```
  n   k z   call
1 foo 100 z k1
2 bar 200 w k2
3 qux 300 x k3
4 qux 400 y k3
5 bar 500 v k2
```

What's the way to do it?

Comment: Just a question what do you mean by "hash call"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for `match`:

> match returns a vector of the positions of (first) matches of its
>   first argument in its second.

```
m <- df1
cbind(m,call=df2$l[match(df1$n ,df2$n2)])
    n   k z call
1 foo 100 z   k1
2 bar 200 w   k2
3 qux 300 x   k3
4 qux 400 y   k3
5 bar 500 v   k2
```

Another option is to use `merge` but you should remove duplicated :

```
hh <- merge(df1,df2,by.x='n',by.y='n2')
hh[!duplicated(hh[,1:3]),]
    n   k z  l
1 bar 200 w k2
3 bar 500 v k2
5 foo 100 z k1
6 qux 300 x k3
8 qux 400 y k3
```